# Synology NAS API get free and total space

Tags: javascript, node.js, synology

I am trying to call the API of a Synology NAS to retrieve information on free space and total space available.

My Login works, and I am getting my Token, requests with that token are shown as "successful".

However, when I try to call for the `list_share` method, with the `additional` value set to `volume_status` which according the documentation of the API should give me the desired data, all I get is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "offset": 0,
        "shares": [],
        "total": 0
    },
    "success": true
}
```

The request I am making is:

`https://NAME:5001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share&additional=volume_status&_sid=TOKEN`

Am I making the wrong request? Do I need to change the Method from `list_share` to `list`?
Am I passing the `additional` value wrong?

The Documentation I am using can be found when googling for '***Synology NAS rest API***'. I inserted the direct download link for the PDF [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiPpPKd0efzAhUL3xoKHZTRAHoQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fglobal.download.synology.com%2Fdownload%2FDocument%2FSoftware%2FDeveloperGuide%2FPackage%2FFileStation%2FAll%2Fenu%2FSynology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Zudc8G6I97Q3yOyBbmJK0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the linked documentation, the additional parameter needs additional brackets and quotes like this:

`https://NAME:5001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share&additional=["volume_status"]&_sid=TOKEN`

Depending on the library you use you might need to encode the brackets and the quotes, but most libraries should do that for you :)

---

**To come to that conclusion, this is what i did:**

In the linked documentation i found the section about list_share and the provided example:

`GET /webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share& additional=%5B%22real_path%22%2C%22owner%2Ctime%22%5D`

This is completely unreadable, since the url is already encoded, but opening the browser console and running

`decodeURIComponent("/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share&additional=%5B%22real_path%22%2C%22owner%2Ctime%22%5D")`

leads me to a readable url:

`/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&version=2&method=list_share&additional=["real_path","owner,time"]`

---

This is an example, how to login, print out the data and logout again:

```js
const http = require("http");

// Helper function to get JSON from an endpoint
function getJson(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      let rawData = "";
      res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        rawData += chunk;
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        try {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
          resolve(parsedData);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

(async () => {
  const host = "synology:5000";
  const user = "userHere";
  const password = "passwordHere";

  // login
  const {
    data: { sid },
  } = await getJson(
    `http://${host}/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=3&account=${user}&passwd=${password}&session=test&format=sid`
  );

  const url = `http://${host}/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&method=list_share&version=2&_sid=${sid}&additional=["volume_status"]`;
  const { data } = await getJson(url);

  data.shares.forEach((share) => {
    console.log(share.name, "-", share.path);
    console.log(share.additional.volume_status);
  });

  //logout
  await getJson(
    `http://${host}/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=logout&version=3&session=test`
  );
})();
```

Comment: This sadly doesnt help, the response is still the same.
Up untill now I didnt even think about using a Library for this case. I am using Nodes HTTPS.request() and encode the options myself. It shouldnt be too much work without a Library as Well since I am testing my requests using Postman which just makes plain GET.

Comment: my initial answer was slightly wrong, did you add the quotation marks aswell?

Comment: after I've seen that you have edited your answer. I tried what you did and then understood what you meant with "encode the brackets". But even after I change my value according to your explanation I am still getting the same answer as before. 

this is what I changed my additional value to: "%5B%22volume_path%22%5D"

Sadly making the example request provided in the documentation is giving the same result as well.

Comment: you are using `volume_path` but you should be using `volume_status`.

Comment: I just checked, how exactly postman encodes my working url:
`/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.List&method=list_share&version=2&sid=___&additional=[%22volume_status%22]`

So it seems the brackets should not be encoded (at least that's how i get a correct response from the api)

Comment: sadly I am still getting the same result as before. Did you manage to recreate the response I am getting? Can you comment your correct Response (with changed values to make it anonym etc)?

Comment: I can try to create an example with node later today.

Comment: @Baul please check my answer for a sample implementation in nodejs :)

Comment: I just checked the output you get once more and even without `additional` the shares array should have some content and total should be > 0. It looks to me like the user doesn't have access to any shares. If this is the case, allowing the user access to the shares should fix that problem

Comment: Well the output is definetly different, thank you very much! I still dont know yet where I can find the information I need. But I hope this will get clear when I reverse engineer your soulution.